# Replace object in array with two objects

Tags: arrays, object, d3.js, replace

I have an array of objects which contain an end and a start date. But the period between dates may straddle midnight. If they do I wish to replace the object with two objects, the first with the previous start date and an end date of midnight. The second with a start time of 00:00 the next day and end date of what it was previously.

So for example if the array contains an object such as this,

```
{
  "start": "2016-11-04 22:00",
  "end": "2016-11-05 03:00"
}
```

I want to replace that object with two objects,

```
{
  "start": "2016-11-04 22:00",
  "end": "2016-11-04 24:00"
},
{
  "start": "2016-11-05 00:00",
  "end": "2016-11-05 03:00"
}
```

Here is my attempt using `data.push()`. Clearly this is not the way to do it:

```
d3.json("data.json", function(data) {
  var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M");
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.commence = parseTime(d.start);
    d.conclude = parseTime(d.end);
    if (d.commence.getDay() != d.conclude.getDay()) {
      midnight = d.commence.getFullYear() + "-" + d.commence.getMonth() + "-" + d.commence.getDay() + " 24:00";
      morning = d.conclude.getFullYear() + "-" + d.conclude.getMonth() + "-" + d.conclude.getDay() + " 00:00";
      data.push({
        "start": d.start,
        "end": midnight
      }, {
        "start": morning,
        "end": d.end
      })
    }
  });
...
```

So how can I add or remove an object as I am iterating through the array of objects?

The data starts like this,

```
[
  {
    "start": "2016-11-01 12:00",
    "end": "2016-11-01 22:00"
  },
  {
    "start": "2016-11-02 02:00",
    "end": "2016-11-02 18:00"
  },
  {
    "start": "2016-11-03 09:00",
    "end": "2016-11-03 12:00"
  },
  {
    "start": "2016-11-04 22:00",
    "end": "2016-11-05 03:00"
  },
  {
    "start": "2016-11-06 12:00",
    "end": "2016-11-06 23:00"
  }
]
```

And in the console I can see it ultimately looks like this,

```
[
  {
    "start": "2016-11-01 12:00",
    "end": "2016-11-01 22:00",
    "commence": "2016-11-01T12:00:00.000Z",
    "conclude": "2016-11-01T22:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2016-11-02 02:00",
    "end": "2016-11-02 18:00",
    "commence": "2016-11-02T02:00:00.000Z",
    "conclude": "2016-11-02T18:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2016-11-03 09:00",
    "end": "2016-11-03 12:00",
    "commence": "2016-11-03T09:00:00.000Z",
    "conclude": "2016-11-03T12:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2016-11-04 22:00",
    "end": "2016-11-05 03:00",
    "commence": "2016-11-04T22:00:00.000Z",
    "conclude": "2016-11-05T03:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2016-11-06 12:00",
    "end": "2016-11-06 23:00",
    "commence": "2016-11-06T12:00:00.000Z",
    "conclude": "2016-11-06T23:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2016-11-04 22:00",
    "end": "2016-10-5 24:00"
  },
  {
    "start": "2016-10-6 00:00",
    "end": "2016-11-05 03:00"
  }
]
```

The full code is on [github](https://github.com/shanegibney/D3-Date-Hours-Graph) and a demo is running on [gh-pages](https://shanegibney.github.io/D3-Date-Hours-Graph/).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `flatMap` concept (functional programming):

```
Array.prototype.flatMap = function(lambda) { 
  return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], this.map(lambda)); 
};

d3.json("data.json", function(data) {

  var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M");
  var formatEndOfDay = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d 24:00");
  var formatStartOfDay = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M");

  var result = data.flatMap( d => {
    var start = parseTime(d.start);
    var end = parseTime(d.end);
    if (start.getDay() == end.getDay())
      return [d];
    else {
      var firstPart = { "start": d.start, "end": formatEndOfDay(start) }
      var secondPart = { "start": formatStartOfDay(end.setHours(0)), "end": d.end }
      return [firstPart, secondPart];
    }
  });

  console.log(result);
});
```

---

```js
Array.prototype.flatMap = function(lambda) { 
  return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], this.map(lambda)); 
};

var data = [
  {
    "start": "2016-11-01 12:00",
    "end": "2016-11-01 22:00"
  },
  {
    "start": "2016-11-02 02:00",
    "end": "2016-11-02 18:00"
  },
  {
    "start": "2016-11-03 09:00",
    "end": "2016-11-03 12:00"
  },
  {
    "start": "2016-11-04 22:00",
    "end": "2016-11-05 03:00"
  },
  {
    "start": "2016-11-06 12:00",
    "end": "2016-11-06 23:00"
  }
];

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M");
var formatEndOfDay = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d 24:00");
var formatStartOfDay = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M");

var result = data.flatMap( d => {
  var start = parseTime(d.start);
  var end = parseTime(d.end);
  if (start.getDay() == end.getDay())
    return [d];
  else {
    var firstPart = { "start": d.start, "end": formatEndOfDay(start) }
    var secondPart = { "start": formatStartOfDay(end.setHours(0)), "end": d.end }
    return [firstPart, secondPart];
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

---

As a reminder, here is an example of `flatMap`: each element of the list is transformed into multiple elements; and these sub-lists are then flattened to produce a list:

```js
Array.prototype.flatMap = function(lambda) { 
  return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], this.map(lambda)); 
};

console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].flatMap(d => d % 2 == 0 ? [d, d] : [d]))
```

Which translates in our case to going through each start/end element, and if an element has its start and end on the same day, then we transform it into a list of 1 element (itself); and if an element doesn't start and end on the same day, then we transform it in a list of 2 elements (first day / end day).

---

As javascript doesn't have a built-in implementation of flatMap, we can create one this way:

```
Array.prototype.flatMap = function(lambda) { 
  return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], this.map(lambda)); 
};
```

Comment: Well this is a sophisticated answer, maybe a lot more than need. I'll have to read up on lambda functions. Thanks for looking at this. I got it to almost work at https://github.com/shanegibney/D3-Date-Hours-Graph but I am having a new problem which I posted about here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49989105/d3-js-datetime-hour-not-displaying-correctly-on-y-axis Thank you for your help, much appreciated